# Replace words in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a simple translation script that will look at a sentence in each cell from a range (column), and translate word by word based on the simple two-column (lookat/replace) translation memory I've created.

If the cell contains

```
"This app is cool"
```

and the translation memory is

```
This | 1
app  | 2
cool | 3
```

Result should be:

```
"1 2 is 3"
```

However, using `.Replace` method, The below string:

```
"This apple from the cooler"
```

Would return

```
"1 2le from the 3er"
```

I used an array and split method to break the sentence into words, and then looked up at each words from my translation list for a `xlwhole` match. I have about 10,000 lines of sentences, and to break down each sentence into words would be roughly about 100,000 words and each word looking through about 1,000 list of translation words. It words.. but kind of slow.

Are there any other way, perhaps a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another regex solution using the replace method and word boundaries (the "\b" in the regex pattern represents a word boundary).  It assumes your source is in column A, and the results will go into column B.

The translation table is hard coded in the macro, but you could easily change that to be picked up from a table in your workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Translate()
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim arrTranslate As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim S As String

V = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
ReDim Preserve V(1 To UBound(V, 1), 1 To 2)

arrTranslate = VBA.Array(Array("This", 1), Array("app", 2), Array("cool", 3))
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
End With

For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    S = V(I, 1)
    For J = 0 To UBound(arrTranslate)
        RE.Pattern = "\b" & arrTranslate(J)(0) & "\b"
        S = RE.Replace(S, arrTranslate(J)(1))
    Next J
    V(I, 2) = S
Next I

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(V, 1), UBound(V, 2))) = V

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 efficiently done. Enjoying the `regexp` solutions.

Comment: I have started to use Regex... Very beautiful Object.

Comment: @brettdj Thank you.  Regex can be slower than straight VBA functions, but it is a heck of a lot easier to program.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for answer. I got it working using the split array way, but will not enjoy much faster approach =]

Answer (score 2):

Word to the rescue: Here I make use of of the "Match whole words only" option in Word's Find/Replace functionality.

```
Dim rngSentences As Range
Dim sentences, translatedSentences, wordsToReplace, newStrings 
Dim iWord As Long
Dim iSentence As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim w As Word.Application
Dim d As Word.Document

Set rngSentences = Range("A1:A5")
wordsToReplace = Array("this", "app", "cool")
newStrings = Array("1", "2", "3")

Set w = New Word.Application
Set d = w.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument)
sentences = rngSentences.Value ' read sentences from sheet
ReDim translatedSentences(LBound(sentences, 1) To UBound(sentences, 1), _
    LBound(sentences, 2) To UBound(sentences, 2))

For iSentence = LBound(sentences, 1) To UBound(sentences, 1)
    'Put sentence in Word document
    d.Range.Text = sentences(iSentence, 1)
    'Replace the words
    For iWord = LBound(wordsToReplace) To UBound(wordsToReplace)
        d.Range.Find.Execute Findtext:=wordsToReplace(iWord), _
            Replacewith:=newStrings(iWord), MatchWholeWord:=True
    Next iWord
    'Grab sentence back from Word doc
    translatedSentences(iSentence, 1) = d.Range.Text
Next iSentence
'slap translated sentences onto sheet
rngSentences.Offset(0, 1) = translatedSentences

w.Quit savechanges:=False
```

Another, potentially faster alternative is to paste all your sentences into the Word doc at once, replace everything, then copy-paste everything back to Excel sheet at once. It may be faster; I don't know, I haven't tested it extensively; up to you to do so.

To implement this, the lines after `Set d = ...` can be replaced with this:

```
'Copy-paste all sentences into Word doc
rngSentences.Copy
d.Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
'Replace words
For iWord = LBound(wordsToReplace) To UBound(wordsToReplace)
    d.Range.Find.Execute Findtext:=wordsToReplace(iWord), Replacewith:=newStrings(iWord), _
        MatchWholeWord:=True
Next iWord
'Copy-paste back to Excel sheet
d.Range.Copy
rngSentences.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
w.Quit savechanges:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use **Regex**.
Following the Scheme:

[image]

The Code:

```
' reference: "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
Dim RegX As Object, Mats As Object, Counter As Long
Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Dim TrA(1 To 1000) As String
Dim TrB(1 To 1000) As String
Dim TrMax As Integer
Dim StrSp

For i = 1 To 9999
    If Range("D" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For
    TrA(i) = Range("D" & i).Value
    TrB(i) = Range("E" & i).Value
    TrMax = i
Next

Range("B1:B10").ClearContents

For i = 1 To 9999
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For

    With RegX
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
        Set Mats = .Execute(Range("A" & i).Value)
    End With

    kk = Range("A" & i).Value
    For Counter = 0 To Mats.Count - 1
        For e = 1 To TrMax
            If LCase(Mats(Counter)) = TrA(e) Then
                kk = Replace(kk, Mats(Counter), TrB(e), , 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Range("B" & i).Value = kk

Next
Set Mats = Nothing
Set RegX = Nothing
```

Regex it's quickly, but the Word code it's very interesting (Copy & Paste ... :-)

Comment: +1 but looping through cells is quite slow; when `TrMax` reaches into the hundreds, this will take a long time to run.